# Query sum for unique pairs of rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet which logs the duration an employee spends in a city. An employee can visit a city multiple times like Peter in this example.

```
City          Person    Days
London        Tom         6
London        Peter       2
Brussels      Josef       1
London        Peter       8
Prague        Ryan        5
Oslo          Peter       4
```

I want to count the total number of days an employee spends in a city. The order should stay the same. So for every unique city-employee pair, all further occurrences get deleted and just the days' count gets summed up. The code should work as well if there are additional columns.

```
City          Person    Days
London        Tom         6
London        Peter       10
Brussels      Josef       1
Prague        Ryan        5
Oslo          Peter       4
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A1:C, "select A,B,sum(C) 
              where C is not null 
              group by A,B
              label sum(C)'Days'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR((VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A1:A&B1:B), QUERY({A1:A&B1:B, A1:C}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,sum(Col4) 
  where Col4 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2,Col3
  label sum(Col4)'Days'", 1), {2,3,4}, 0))))
```

[image: 0]